# Вызвать метод через 3 секунды после нажатия Button

Tags: c#, winforms

Необходимо вызвать метод через 3 секунды после старта таймера, который сигнализируется нажатием на кнопку.

```
private void ReadyLearn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();

    ........

    метод();    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно подождать асинхронно и таймер не понадобится.

```
private async void ReadyLearn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(3000);

    метод();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Timer timer1;

public void Ctor() 
{
    timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.Tick += (o, e) => 
    {    
        метод(); 
        timer1.Stop();
    };

    timer1.Interval = 3000;
}

private void ReadyLearn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();   
}
```

Comment: При каждом нажатии на кнопку будет добавляться новый обработчик тика. Нужно отписываться от предыдущего. Либо подписаться один раз где-нибудь в конструкторе формы.